# Couldn't start dlv dap

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

When I launch in VSCode dlv dap debug, I get this message:

```
Couldn't start dlv dap:
Error:timed out while waiting for DAP server to start
```

[image]

I already have launch configurations for the project：

lunch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch file",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "showLog": true,
        "env": {
            "GO111MODULE": "on"
        }
    }
]
}
```

and setting.json is :

```
{
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "."
    }
],
"settings": {
    "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggestWithoutType": true,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true, 
    "go.gocodePackageLookupMode": "go",
    "go.gotoSymbol.includeImports": true,
    "go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "go.docsTool": "gogetdoc",
    "go.buildFlags": [],
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0.8,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.delveConfig":{
        "debugAdapter":"dlv-dap"
        },
    "[go]": {
        "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true
        }
    },
    "gopls": {
        "experimentalWorkspaceModule": true,
        "usePlaceholders": true, // add parameter placeholders when completing a function
        "completionDocumentation": true // for documentation in completion items
    }
},
    
}
```

The structure of the project is shown in the figure：

[image]

Comment: sorry for the trouble. I filed an issue https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1693. Can you please check if you could run `dlv-dap.exec dap --listen=:12345 --log --log-output=dap` without any issue, and provide how long it takes to show messages like "DAP server listening at: ..." in the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Now, it worked after i restart the  system(win10) (it hasn't shut down for a long time before that). And the problem hasn't been repeated so far. I'm very sorry i can't check the time and thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have some luck switching the delveConfig to use legacy mode:

```
    "go.delveConfig":{
        "debugAdapter":"legacy"
        }
```

My team and I recently began seeing the same issue after updating VSCode. There's a little more info on this setting here: https://go.googlesource.com/vscode-go/+/HEAD/docs/debugging.md#switching-to-legacy-debug-adapter, but I believe root cause (if this does indeed solve your issue) is going to be your version of Golang is not the version targeted by dlv-dap. Anything below Go version 1.15 needs to use legacy mode, and the latest version of the delve debugger happens to skip legacy mode by default now.

I also needed to kill VSCode before this change took effect. According to the dlv-dap docs, you can also force it into legacy mode by switching launch.json's mode to "remote", so there's likely a few (maybe better) ways to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It worked if use legacy mode, but if  i want to use dlv-dap mode, what else do I need to do?   
 windows 10   Vscode 1.59.0
      set GOOS=windows
    set GOPATH=D:\Code\Go
    set GOROOT=D:\Programs\go
    set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
    set GOVERSION=go1.16.6

Comment: Since you're on a version greater than Golang 1.15, you should be able to use the default "dlv-dap" mode without needing the legacy adapter.

Are you attempting remote debugging? According to their docs in the link I shared above, remote debugging still requires the legacy adapter.

Take a look at your launch.json. If you'd like to do non-remote debugging, make sure that:
*mode* is "debug", *port* is not set, and *remotePath*, if present, equals ""

Comment: No, I want to use the dlv-dap mode for local debugging. According to the docs you shared, if *request* is **launch**, the attribute of *remotePath* is not applicable. And In my project, the launch configurations is 
```
{
        "name": "Launch file",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "showLog": true,
        "env": {
            "GO111MODULE": "on"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was able to solve another similar problem by setting this to `dlv-dap`. I'm referring to the early returned `EOF` error. You saved my life, thanks!

Answer (score 31):

This might be happening due to recent updates to [VS Code Go extension](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/).

**First options** is to fix it by running `"Go: Install/Update Tools"` command from the Command Palette (***Linux/Windows***: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, ***Mac***: <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).

Then, mark `dlv` & `dlv-dap` from the menu, and hit **ok** to start install/update.

> Delve’s native DAP implementation is under active development, so take advantage of the most recent features and bug fixes by using Delve built from its master branch. The Go extension maintains this newest version of Delve **separately** from the officially released version of dlv and installs it with the name dlv-dap.

**Second option**, is to use legacy debug adapter. More on this in the link below ...

Check out the full documentation at https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Comment: This would serve as a better accepted answer than the current one.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS users:

```
brew install delve
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Windows: Ctrl+Shift+P, Mac: ⇧+⌘+P
[image]

[image]

Comment: Screenshot only answers with minimal text like this aren't very helpful. Consider adding some textual explanation.